# OpenCV Mat to Gstreamer pipeline with filesink option writing files of only 336 bytes

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer, nvidia

As the title suggests, I have a opencv Mat downloaded from gpu mat after converting it to BGRA:

```
cv::cuda::cvtColor(src,src,cv::COLOR_RGB2BGRA); //src - gpuMat
src.download(display_img); //display_mg - cpuMat
```

Then I want to save this frames to a file by using gstreamer and hardware encoder.

The setup I am using is nvidia jetson xavier agx with hardware encoder.
I have tried creating a pipeline like so:

```
cv::VideoWriter gst_nvh264_writer("appsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx !queue! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc ! video/x-h264,format=byte-stream ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test-nvh264-writer.mkv ", 0, 30, cv::Size (400,400));
```

```
if (!gst_nvh264_writer.isOpened ()) {
    std::cout << "Failed to open gst_nvh264 writer." << std::endl;
```

And finally I'm writing the frames to the pipeline like:

```
gst_nvh264_writer.write(display_img);
```

But its outputting a file of only 336 bytes. The size is of the mat is fixed to 400x400 and I think stride values should be managed by the pipeline. So I assume the problem is with the pipeline creation parameters and I'm new to gstreamer.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: why do you want BGRA here ? i dont think, VideoCapture supports that (and it looks like it only wrote the matroshka header, but not a single frame)

Comment: You should edit the question for readability separating codes and paragraphs clearly. Anyway you are not specifying the input format of the videoconvert plugin and the nvvidconv plugin do not support the BGRx input.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Ive changed it to BGR and now its writing to mkv files and its playing. Thanks a lot! However when I try to use mp4mux or qtmux to write to mp4 files, then the file size is increasing but not playable. It seems you have to give some EOS signal and/or the size/no of buffers as input but Im not sure how. Any ideas in this matter is welcome. Thanks a lot again.